# Qual è il senso di questo uso figurato di "rincarare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*,  di Erri De Luca, ho letto questo paragrafo che si riferisce all'atteggiamento di una vecchia governante e alla reazione della madre dell'autore di fronte a questo:

> Mi accorgevo qualche volta di un suo improvviso silenzio sotto una sequenza di rimproveri. Di solito replicava il tutt’altro che riusciva a intendere, con voce alta per la preoccupazione di spiegarsi a suo modo quello che le stavi dicendo. Ripeteva le tue parole sbagliandole, rispondeva concitatamente scuse imbrogliate. Questo aveva l’effetto sicuro di **rincarare** il tuo disappunto.

Ho cercato "rincarare" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che, in senso proprio, 
significa aumentare i prezzi. In senso figurato, esiste l'espressione "rincarare la dose" che significa aggravare un'accusa, un rimprovero, un danno o un dispiacere. Ma sembra che l'unico utilizzo in senso figurato sia nella frase fatta "rincarare la dose". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: il significato in questo contesto sarebbe quello di aggravare il disappunto della madre?

Comment: Opinione personalissima: in mille anni di letteratura italiana, dalla scuola poetica siciliana a Cognetti e la Di Pietrantonio, io non perderei troppo tempo con De Luca.

Comment: @DaG: Ho letto un paio di libri di De Luca in precedenza e, veramente, non è lo stile che mi piace di più. Ma perlomeno questo, che è davvero molto corto, finisco di leggerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È corretto il tuo ragionamento, in questo contesto è un sinonimo di "aumentare"; leggendo il termine "rincarare" provi anche un leggero senso di fastidio aggiuntivo dovuto alla metafora implicita di un aumento di prezzo ingiustificato.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!